# event.target.name giving undifined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

When I try to send the the value from input component to handlesumbit function in console.log inside function I receive event.target.name for variable cName undefined.

```
 @connect((store) => {
            return {
                nameOfCity:store.nameOfCity.nameOfCity,
                weatherDescription:store.weatherDescription.weatherDescription,
                windSpeed:store.windSpeed.windSpeed,
                temperature:store.temperature.temperature,
                maxTemperature:store.maxTemperature.maxTemperature,
                minTemperature:store.minTemperature.minTemperature,
            }
        })

        class FormContainer extends Component {

            handleFormSubmit(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                let cName = event.target.name;
                console.log(cName);
                this.props.dispatch(fetchWeatherData(cName));
            }

            render() {
                return (
                    <div>
                    <form onSubmit={this.handleFormSubmit.bind(this)}>
                        <label>{this.props.label}</label>
                        <SearchBar
                            name="CityName"
                            type="text"
                            value={this.props.cityName}
                            placeholder="search"
                        />

                        <button type="submit" className="" value='Submit' placeholder="Search">Search</button>
                    </form>
                    </div>
                );
            }
        }
```

SearchBar component

```
    const SearchBar = (props) => (
        <div>
            <label>{props.label}</label>
            <input name={props.name} type="text" defaultValue={props.value} placeholder={props.placeholder}/>
        </div>
    );
    export default SearchBar;
```

EDIT: Why is that var undefined shouldn't that be passed

Comment: The computer is always right. THat variable is probably indeed undefined.

Comment: i added a question

Comment: Because your argument in `handleFormSubmit` is called `e` not `event`. Should be `e.target.name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing *event* with `e` variable to `handleFormSubmit`, Thus `event` object is undefined there, and because its defined no where, it will correctly return `undefined`.

Just change `e` to `event` in `handeFormSubmit` argument.